# Powerpoint 2013 - Change font size effect

Tags: animation, microsoft-powerpoint-2013, visual-effects

Is there a way I can change the font size using animation in MS Power Point 2013?

Grow/Shrink is terrible, it pixelates and mess up the line tab.

I think it was possible to do in previews version, 2007.